# Install ghost blog meet `npm WARN cannot run in wd ghost`

Tags: ghost-blog

while I download ghost ,and unzip it to new_ghost ,then i meet this error

```
➜  new_ghost npm install --production
npm WARN cannot run in wd ghost@0.11.2 node core/server/utils/npm/preinstall.js (wd=/var/www/new_ghost)
[1]    14831 killed     npm install --production
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in package.json you will see the preinstall script. It is looking for node. If you are working on Ubuntu, you might need to change that to nodejs. Another thing to try is:

```
npm cache clean
rm -rf node_modules
npm install --production
npm start --production
```

Another possibility is if you are using a version of node that it doesn't support. In that case you can disable the version check:

```
GHOST_NODE_VERSION_CHECK=false npm install --production
GHOST_NODE_VERSION_CHECK=false npm start --production
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
As mentioned by the Ghost folks here http://support.ghost.org/troubleshooting/#npm-start-issues, you should enable or increase the swap size.

If you don't have swap enabled, you can follow the guide here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-12-04